# Report Viewer Problems

Tags: asp.net

I have an error how to fix this thanks in advance:) the datasource1 shows overload resolution failed because no accessible 'new' is more specific for there arguments.

```
    ReportViewer1.Visible = True

    Dim thisDataSet As New DataSet()

    Dim adapCategory As DataSetParameterTableAdapters.mCategoryTableAdapter = New DataSetParameterTableAdapters.mCategoryTableAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSetParameter.mCategoryDataTable = New DataSetParameter.mCategoryDataTable()
    adapCategory.Fill(ds, Me.DropDownList1.SelectedValue)

    Dim datasource1 As New ReportDataSource("DataSetParameter_mCategory", ds)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1)

    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your `ds` instance of the `DataSet` object does not match the requirements for the `ReportDataSource(String, Object)` constructor.  See [this MSDN reference for that constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms251824%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Also, quoting the remarks from that link:

> Value may be an instance of `DataTable`, a `IEnumerable` value (for
>   example, `DataView` or `Array`), or a `IDataSource`.

The problem is you're trying to pass a `DataSet` object, and that is neither a `DataTable`, nor does it implement `IEnumerable` or `IDataSource`.

In other words, you can't pass a `DataSet` object to this constructor.  The solution would be to pull the appopriate `DataTable` out of that `DataSet` and pass *that* `DataTable` instance to the constructor.